# ISNULL and Lead Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ISNULL(LEAD(R.StartTime,1) OVER ( ORDER BY R.StartTime), 'No Next Lesson') as NextClass
```

I am not converting anything here, still it throws the same error. Please help.

datatype of R.StartTime is datetime. Tried casting as time, still nothing.

The answers in the other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643216/t-sql-conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string) didnt help

Comment: This is telling you the problem; `'No Next Lesson'` is *not* a valid date and time value. `ISNULL` returns the datatype of the **first** parameter. One would assume that `StartTime` is a date and time value, based on the name and the error, and so the failure is then quite obvious.

Comment: I have *assumed* you are using SQL Server here, based on the [[tag:tsql]] tag. If you are using a different product that uses T-SQL, such as Azure Synapse or Sybase, please [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Comment: So CAST as varchar would do the trick then @Larnu.

Comment: Personally, I've leave it as `NULL` and have the presentation layer display the value differently. I am not a fan of converting dates to string based datatypes, as that can easily affect how comparison and ordering works.  For example `'12-01-2002'` is **after** `'10-11-2022'`.

Comment: How'd we do that, I am new to this, using VueJs for front end and C# for backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @Larnu helped:

if you match the datatype in ISNULL, error is resolved.

> "This is telling you the problem; 'No Next Lesson' is not a valid date and time value. ISNULL returns the datatype of the first parameter. One would assume that StartTime is a date and time value, based on the name and the error, and so the failure is then quite obvious"